# Equivalent JOIN queries without using OR in filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying something with the queries and come across a situation where I want to get an **equivalent JOIN queries for the following queries without using OR** . It's OK if we add more JOIN statements for the same table. It's also OK if we have two queries for the same query.

**Query 1**

```
DECLARE @id INT =1
DECLARE @id2 INT =1

UPDATE  pra
SET     pra.table2col6  = 0,
        pra.table2col7 = 0
FROM    #table1 prr
INNER JOIN table2 pra
    ON  pra.table2col1  = @id
    AND pra.table2col2  = prr.table1col2
    AND pra.table2col3  < prr.table1col3
    AND  ((pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3
             AND  pra.table2col5  = 0)
         OR (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 --OR part which I want to break
             AND  pra.table2col5  = 1))
    AND (pra.table2col6      = 1
        OR  pra.table2col7 = 1)  --OR part which I want to break
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT prr.col1, pra.col2
FROM #table1 prr
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 pra
    ON   pra.table2col1   = @id
    AND  pra.table2col2   = prr.table1col2
    AND  pra.table2col3  = 2        
    AND  ((pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3
             AND  pra.table2col5  = 0)
         OR (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 --OR part which I want to break
             AND  pra.table2col5  = 1))
WHERE pra.table2col1 IS NULL
    AND prr.CreatedAt >= @id2
```

**Solution of Query2 (likely?)**

```
SELECT prr.col1, pra.col2
FROM #table1 prr
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 pra
    ON   pra.table2col1   = @id
    AND  pra.table2col2   = prr.table1col2
    AND  pra.table2col3  = 2        
    AND  pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3
    AND  pra.table2col5  = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 pra2 --added one more LEFT OUTER JOIN assuming this query is equivalent to Query1
    ON   pra2.table2col1   = @id
    AND  pra2.table2col2   = prr.table1col2
    AND  pra2.table2col3  = 2        
    AND  pra2.table2col4 = prr.table1col4
    AND  pra.table2col5  = 1
WHERE pra.table2col1 IS NULL AND pra2.table2col1 IS NULL
    AND prr.CreatedAt >= @id2
```

*1. Does solution look good for Query2*

*2. How can I expand the INNER JOIN of Query 1 so that I'll get equivalent query without using OR*

Comment: It would possible to suggest you better if you share sample input and output data.

Comment: you can however use the "fun" boolean logic to re-write `or` into `and`. for example : `(a and b) or (c and d)` is same as `not(not(a and b) and not(c and d))` .

Comment: will be difficult to share the sample data but I assume this is more of a venn diagram problem.

Comment: @DaleK how will the above query look with UNION ALL?

Comment: @DaleK both of the queries were related and it seems they were just variation of INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN. Moreover, I thought I had solution of Query2 so I just wanted to add here for better context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be interesting to know *why* you wish to remove the `OR`'s. Given you have 2 `OR` conditions, you can remove them by splitting this into 4 `update` statements, where each `update` takes care of one combination e.g.

```
UPDATE pra SET
  pra.table2col6 = 0
  , pra.table2col7 = 0
FROM #table1 prr
INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
  AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
  AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
  -- left side or 1
  AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3 AND pra.table2col5 = 0)
  -- left side or 2
  AND pra.table2col6 = 1;

UPDATE pra SET
  pra.table2col6 = 0
  , pra.table2col7 = 0
FROM #table1 prr
INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
  AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
  AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
  -- left side or 1
  AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3 AND pra.table2col5 = 0)
  -- right side or 2
  AND pra.table2col7 = 1;

UPDATE pra SET
  pra.table2col6 = 0
  , pra.table2col7 = 0
FROM #table1 prr
INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
  AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
  AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
  -- right side or 1
  AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 AND pra.table2col5 = 1)
  -- left side or 2
  AND pra.table2col6 = 1;

UPDATE pra SET
  pra.table2col6 = 0
  , pra.table2col7 = 0
FROM #table1 prr
INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
  AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
  AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
  -- right side or 1
  AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 AND pra.table2col5 = 1)
  -- right side or 2
  AND pra.table2col7 = 1;
```

If you prefer a single `update` statement, and your `pra` table has an `id` you could use the `union all` approach within an updatable CTE e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT pra.id
      , pra.table2col6
      , pra.table2col7
    FROM #table1 prr
    INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
      AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
      AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
      -- left side or 1
      AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3 AND pra.table2col5 = 0)
      -- left side or 2
      AND pra.table2col6 = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pra.id
      , pra.table2col6
      , pra.table2col7
    FROM #table1 prr
    INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
      AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
      AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
      -- left side or 1
      AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3 AND pra.table2col5 = 0)
      -- right side or 2
      AND pra.table2col7 = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pra.id
      , pra.table2col6
      , pra.table2col7
    FROM #table1 prr
    INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
      AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
      AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
      -- right side or 1
      AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 AND pra.table2col5 = 1)
      -- left side or 2
      AND pra.table2col6 = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pra.id
      , pra.table2col6
      , pra.table2col7
    FROM #table1 prr
    INNER JOIN table2 pra ON pra.table2col1 = @id
      AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
      AND pra.table2col3 < prr.table1col3
      -- right side or 1
      AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 AND pra.table2col5 = 1)
      -- right side or 2
      AND pra.table2col7 = 1;
)
UPDATE cte SET
    table2col6 = 0
    , table2col7 = 0;
```

And for query 2 use a `union all`

```
SELECT prr.col1, pra.col2
FROM #table1 prr
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 pra
    ON pra.table2col1 = @id
    AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
    AND pra.table2col3 = 2
    -- left side of or
    AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col3 AND pra.table2col5 = 0)
WHERE pra.table2col1 IS NULL AND prr.CreatedAt >= @id2

UNION ALL

SELECT prr.col1, pra.col2
FROM #table1 prr
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 pra
    ON pra.table2col1 = @id
    AND pra.table2col2 = prr.table1col2
    AND pra.table2col3 = 2
    -- right side of or
    AND (pra.table2col4 = prr.table1col4 AND pra.table2col5 = 1)
WHERE pra.table2col1 IS NULL AND prr.CreatedAt >= @id2
```

Comment: I was working on testing few perf scenarios and wanted these queries for comparison. does the solution of Query 2 looks good?

Comment: needed these queries for testing performance scenarios. thank you for the answer. just a quick check whether there is an issue with the solution I proposed for Query 2

Comment: @Rahulsingh the best way to check whether query 2 works for you is to run it and see if it works. I don't believe it will, joining the table onto itself again gives you more columns, not more rows. But as always, try it! Thats the best way to verify a query.